# Return a list of values using Json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller action, I call a method that returns me a a list of missing files. From here, I return this list to the .js file using Json:

```
foreach (string s in result.Value.MissingImages)
{
            missingImages.Add(s.ToString());
}
return Json(new { returnVal= missingImages });
```

On the .js file, I would like to display a list of these files to the users. How should I process and display this list on the front end?

```
$("#Images").click(function () {
            $.post('/File/ImageUtil', function (data) {                              
                //display the missing file list to the user here??             
            });
        });
```

Comment: use firebug for view the format of the json respone and travels over the json object..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a result placeholder:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

and then loop through the returned collection of strings and inject them into the result:

```
$("#Images").click(function () {
    $.post('/File/ImageUtil', function (data) {
        var result = $('#result');
        result.empty();
        $.each(data.returnVal, function() {
            result.append(
                $('<div/>', {
                    text: this
                })
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

More complicated rendering requires better knowledge of your browser side rendering.

Comment: OK - so the above gets me a list of missing files as a collection of strings? What is the best way to show that list to the users. Sorry, I am new to jQuery!

Comment: @GoldenUser You may want to start accepting some answers if you want more help.

Comment: @GoldenUser, every browser have developer/debugging tools built in - set break point and see what "data" is. Decide how to render items and do that - there is no "the best way" to do it, just hundreds of good ways.